# PINCH-ZOOM second time touch producing error

Tags: android

In my app when I first touch two fingers the distance between it is calculated.

This distance is compared with the old distance initially set to 10 in the `onCreate()` method. Zoom in or zoom out is done comparing these distances. Everything is fine till here.

But during the second time when the fingers are again touched the old distance (the new distance before the fingers are lifted) that is already set is greater than the new distance (distance between the fingers now touched) or is less then new distance (distance between the fingers now touched) -ISSUE-resulting in zoom out/Zoom in which is not desirable.

ISSUE: I want a method in OnGestureListener which will be executed just once when the fingers are lifted up. NOTE::`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is not producing results.

How can I fix this problem?